# Disk naming convention in preseed vs manual installation

Tags: 12.04, disk, system-installation, devices

When I try to install Ubuntu 12.04 onto a Dell PowerEdge R710 via preseed, the auto install first disk is always coming up as `/dev/sdc`. As per the docs it should be `/dev/sda`.

I looked at `/var/lib/partman/devices`, its does show `/dev/sdc`.

On the same server if I try to install Ubuntu 12.04 manually then the first disk showing as `/dev/sda`.

Any idea why preseed auto install and manual install have different disk naming conventions?

Comment: Disk letters depend in part on the order in which the drivers were loaded, which can be a bit random. Why does it matter anyway?

Comment: I have common preseed file between different physical assets. Example Dell, Cisco etc. Using preseed auto install options I just want to install onto the first disk. In this case I cant use the same preseed file between hardwares. Cisco it shows as /dev/sda as the first and dell it shows as /dev/sdc.

Comment: I think you can add some udev rules to your preseed. But you'll have to define what you mean by “first disk”.

Comment: Thanks will try that. FirstDisk I meant /dev/sda. As per ubuntu docs first disk they mentioned as /dev/sda and I am using partman-auto/disk /dev/sda property in preseed file                                                           # For example, to use the first SCSI/SATA hard disk:
#d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda

Answer (score 0):

Check your Virtual Media settings in iDRAC6. I had Virtual Media attached with Floppy Emulation checked on one of my R710's that kept displacing the SCSI disk ID's from sda to sdc. Detaching and unchecking fixed it and I was able to preseed without issue (with sda specified in partman).

You will also see in the system BIOS an extra Virtual Floppy and Virtual CD selection in Boot Options. I didn't check to see if you can disable the Virtual Media here.

Here's how to check via racadm:

```
/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/racadm -r DRACIP -u root -p XXX getconfig -gcfgRacVirtual
Security Alert: Certificate is invalid - self signed certificate
Continuing execution. Use -S option for racadm to stop execution on certificate-related errors.
cfgVirMediaAttached=1                                                        
cfgVirtualBootOnce=0
cfgVirMediaFloppyEmulation=1
cfgLCDriveEnable=1
```

To fix use:

```
racadm config -g cfgRacVirtual -o cfgVirMediaAttached 0 
racadm config -g cfgRacVirtual -o cfgVirMediaFloppyEmulation 0
```